# What is the smallest launch vehicle that has put a satellite in a geostationary orbit?

Tags: history, launch-vehicle, geosynchronous, north-korea

Minotaur V might become a candidate for the smallest current launcher to put a payload in GEO, but it has only launched LADEE yet. The first satellite in GEO seems to have been [Syncom 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syncom) which launched on a [Delta B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_(rocket_family)#Delta_B) in 1963. There are different ways of being the smallest to consider.

North Korea has announced that they will launch geostationary satellites. How does the capability of their launchers thus far meet that ambition?

Comment: Isn't "How does the capability of (North Korea's) launchers thus far meet that ambition (of geostationary launch)?" a completely different question than "What is the smallest launcher that has put a satellite in geostationary orbit"? Or are they linked (perhaps because if they did, it would be the smallest)?

Comment: NK announcement; https://www.realcleardefense.com/articles/2017/10/31/north_koreas_space_program_aims_higher_112554.html and http://www.newsweek.com/star-wars-north-koreas-unveils-5-year-plan-conquer-space-695896